# What SSL version is used to log data to Application Insights from desktop application?

Tags: azure-application-insights

Comparing to June, in July we have a significant drop of users (97%) from Windows XP in our Windows desktop app. Is it possible that Application Insights switched its endpoint certificate to TLS 1.2 or something else that is not supported by Windows XP?

Comment: I don't see any announcements about TLS enforcement changes for App Insights endpoints, but I will check with the product team.

Comment: Thank you! I would appreciate any info that may impact collecting data from XP app instances.

Answer (score 0):

I got a response from someone on the App Insights team that has knowledge of that area. As we create new regions they will have TLS < 1.2 disabled but existing areas are still backwards compatible, so unless you recently migrated to a newly created region this isn't the cause of the issue.

There is a fairly large [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-troubleshoot-no-data) for App Insights missing data. Two things stand out at me as possible next steps. The first is firewalls. I don't know how your app is distributed, but the IP addresses associated with App Insights do change occasionally, so if there are firewall rules in place to allow App Insights outbound traffic, it is worth validating that against the [current list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses).

The second is if you can get logs from one of the affected machines App Insights does do event logging that I believe will be available in XP. There is a list of event sources on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/tree/master/Samples/ETW